# Is it possible to disable the "Activate Google Now" reminder every time you use "Google Search Widget"?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, app-widgets, google-now, google-search

I've started to use Android 4.X for the first time (after being a long term Android 2.3.X user) and some things are new to me.

One of the things that annoy me more is the "new Google Search Widget", which is displayed onto one of my Samsung Galaxy S3 4.1.2 desktop pages. It works nicely.

But, whenever I try to launch said Google search widget, Google annoys me with an (apparently unavoidable) reminder about joining Google Now. The only button they offer is a "next" button (which of course, I don't want to press).

I just dismiss this nagging screen pressing the "back butotn".

But as soon as I reopen the google search widget, the "join google now" reminder is there again. I'm afraid I'll press the "next" button in a distraction, and then I'll be "doomed forever".

So, is there any method to really get rid of this popup? I'll never join "Google Now", in the same manner I just avoid Google + at all costs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep clicking on the `Next` button as if you are agreeing. Then you can choose 'No, Maybe Later` to opt out of [google-now](/questions/tagged/google-now). When you perform a normal search under your previous searches/ suggested searches there is a link to "Get Google Now" again! You can click the big <kbd>X</kbd> beside it and it will not come back. However, some updates and reinstalling the search app may cause this to recur again, but the steps above will get rid of it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [androiddevelopersltd.com](http://www.androiddevelopersltd.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/01fc7_android_Google-Now-permission-screenshot.png))</sub>

Comment: Excellent, apparently it worked. I'm more than sure Google will ask again, but now the widget is snappier than ever. Thanks!!

Comment: @friguron I don't doubt it will pop up again some time... Do you want Google Now NOW? ;)

Comment: "Now" I don't :( :(